# Do we ever see the hamster wheel that powers the Enterprise-D in a TNG episode or in 'Generations'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, spaceship

I recently read an entry in the *[Star Trek Encyclopedia](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671536095)* which noted that there were a lot of little 'in-jokes' on the *Enterprise-D*'s [Master Display in Engineering](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Master_systems_display_table), including a Porsche.  One of the most famous was a hamster wheel which supposedly powered the *Enterprise-D* (if you thought it was the warp core, you were wrong!).  My question is then: **do we ever see this hamster wheel on the Master Display in a TNG episode or *Generations*?**

Answer (score 52):

#### Took some searching, but I finally found him...

[image]

Thank [**Cracked**](http://www.cracked.com/blog/5-ways-star-trek-federation-evil-empire/) for the image

Edit

Thanks Hypnosifl to for the comment:

> The image is apparently from [Star Trek The Tour](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_The_Exhibition), see Joel Zink's photo gallery [here](https://joelzink.smugmug.com/Misc/Star-Trek-The-Tour/) which has an identical image. So, this doesn't really answer the original question about whether it was ever seen on TNG.

So it appears this is not actually from an episode of TNG, but still proof perhaps that it exists.

Comment: I notice that it's spun the wheel too fast and is now upside down. Does this have any consequences for the warp field?

Comment: @Random832 Obviously yes it does. Many consequences...

Comment: @Random832 I think it's just another instance of reversing the polarity.

Comment: The Cracked article doesn't mention if this image was actually taken from an episode. I would love a reference to an episode where this can be seen on screen (if paused at the right time and magnified, of course).

Comment: Any reason that it's a cat instead of a hamster?  Or do they make long-tailed hamsters with necks?

Comment: @JPhi1618 It might be a mouse, but I'm pretty sure it's not a cat.

Comment: @Josh - The image is apparently from [Star Trek The Tour](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek_The_Exhibition), see Joel Zink's photo gallery [here](https://joelzink.smugmug.com/Misc/Star-Trek-The-Tour/) which has an identical image. So, this doesn't really answer the original question about whether it was ever seen on TNG.

Comment: @Daft Terrible, terrible damage.

Comment: I agree with @Hypnosifl I'm afraid; if this image isn't actually from in a *TNG* episode it's not valid!  Still, good proof that it does exist :D

Comment: @Random832 It caused them to lose inertial dampers, helm control, life support and shields, like every other gust of wind in the universe does to them :)

Comment: @TheDoc yep, I guess your right. I just seen the hamster in his wheel and got excited! :)

Comment: @Daft No worries; your answer is certainly worth the upvotes - great work :D

Answer (score 6):

This is an image from episode [11001001 (1x15)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/11001001_(episode)) in which Picard and Riker initiate self destruct in engineering. Frame grab at 33mins 14 seconds.

Now admittedly this is season 1, but you can clearly see that is does NOT match the "The Tour" image in Daft's answer, and does not show the wheel.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a slightly different display. Note the lack of yellow semicircles.

Comment: Agreed. As I said, this is season 1 and I suspect the display evolved over time. I will keep an eye out for a decent shot in season 7

Comment: That also looks like a screenshot from the 1080p remastered TNG, so I wouldn't expect to see it anyway.  In this case both versions lack the hamster wheel, but in others the remastered versions have the gags removed. Presumably since with the greatly increased resolution they were far less subtle.  The little gags visible in some of the Mind's Eye close ups were removed when remastered for example: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mind's_Eye_(episode)#Continuity

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the hamster wheel, but you can see a blurry version of some of the other gags in the original version of "[The Mind's Eye](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mind%27s_Eye_(episode)#Continuity)" (4x24), but these were digitally removed in the 1080p remastered version.

Here's a gif showing the difference (low quality due to gif size limit): https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6juc.gif

[image]

Here's the original SD release in full detail:

[image]

Gags removed: a "slippery when wet" sign, an outline of a person and child, and a handicap sign.  Here's the closeups:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see some of those in detail in this fan photo of the set I found [online here](https://joelzink.smugmug.com/Misc/Star-Trek-The-Tour/i-czK6Lqx/A).

[image]

In the 1080p remastered version of this episode, you can see that they've been removed.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please note that the question was specifically about the hamster wheel, which you don't mention at all.

Comment: yea... good point! I edited it to clarify. Though the top answer is a fan photo from a star trek exhibition and not actually from the "Master Display in a TNG episode or Generations".  So figured related answers that comply with that part of the question would be interesting!

Comment: That "fan photo" has shapes not seen on the original schematic - could it be just a joke for the exhibition where the photo was taken?

Comment: @HorusKol good point! Might not even have existed during the filming... and it was added later for the fan exhibit in-line with the other gags in the Master Display.