# Who starts the Starship Enterprise, and how do they start it?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, spaceship

Who starts the Starship Enterprise, and how do they start it?

Is it a key, a button, a fob, a lever, or what?

Or is it something more esoteric, like a kick start, jump start, or even a rolling start, much like my old truck?

Does it make any sounds when it starts?

***Extra points:*** *Does it vary by the version of the Enterprise?*

Comment: I have no idea, but I imagine they have to "turn on" Engineering.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and then back on again?

Comment: I would imagine that you could just say "Computer, start the engines" or "Computer, start the ship" but you might have to do something to turn the computer on. So it might be simple push-button switch like the computers we have now.

Comment: @Andrew It used to be "Xbox go home" but this produced unwanted side effects when addressing a vehicle.

Comment: No one knows. Scotty retired, and now they are afraid to shut it off.

Comment: @JK. I believe there is actually a TNG episode where they do that, although I forget which one. (I’m currently in the middle of a re-watch, so it’s definitely after season 4, episode 18.)

Comment: You never see it, but Geordi turns a huge crank on the back of the warp drive :,)

Comment: This is a bit like asking how do you start up a WWII aircraft carrier or a nuclear power plant. It wouldn't be by turning a single switch, it ought to be a long and complex process that might take weeks or months starting from completely cold. An interstellar spaceship is a bit more complex than your '65 F-100 ;-)

Comment: @maguirenumber6: ridiculous! Why would Geordi turn a huge crank when [they’ve already got the hamster wheel??](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108143/do-we-ever-see-the-hamster-wheel-that-powers-the-enterprise-d-in-a-tng-episode-o)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The hamster wheel is a backup. It's one of Star Trek's great secrets :'D

Answer (score 7):

## The Matter/Antimatter Assembly is the "key".

My answer is based on the Enterprise D and sourced from the official *Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual* by Michael Okuda and Rick Sterbach (the two principal production designers on *TNG*).  I presume this answer holds for most *TNG*-era Starfleet-designed starships, including the Enterprise E and possibly the Enterprise C (two decades prior to D).

According to the Manual (Section 5.2 on the Matter/Antimatter Assembly), ***the engine start-up sequence is what "turns on" the ship in general.***

> As the entire engine system undergoes start-up, the energetic plasma generated...

...is distributed across the ship via the **PTCs** (power transfer conduits).  The power is accessed by various on-board systems using the **EPS** (electro-plasma system) relays, which have three types of power taps, depending on the system or device that will draw energy from the relay.  (I've had to paraphrase a couple of pages worth of technobabble.)

Fundamentally, engine initialization via the matter/antimatter assembly is controlled via Engineering.  (It can be modulated from the Bridge, but if the EPS relays and power distribution manifolds have no power to distribute, Bridge systems will be offline and a "cold start" directly from Engineering is required.)

As for how the ship is turned on ("button, fob, lever..."), presumably one has to physically open the matter/antimatter intermix chamber and allow matter and antimatter to mix (assuming we are attempting a completely "cold start" in which all consoles are inoperative).  This is not described in the Manual, but it seems reasonable to me.

**Note:** We see the Enterprise D completely "off" in the episode ["Starship Mine"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starship_Mine_(episode)) for a baryon sweep, but we aren't explicitly shown the reinitialization sequence.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you elaborate on the "nearly off" state that can be obtain from the bridge versus a "completely off" state?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard : I meant more that it can be powered up from a nearly off state.  If the EPS relays and power distribution manifolds have no power to distribute, then the bridge consoles will be "off" and one has to do a "cold start" from Engineering directly.  I'll clarify in the answer.

Comment: Might be worth noting that we see the ship in a low-power mode in many situations....but there's one specific time that we see it "off" - it's in the episode where the Enterprise is docked for the Baryon sweep. (Bonus - Tim Russ is in this episode as an antagonist.) Offhand I don't think we ever see a full startup sequence for any Star Trek ship, as systems are usually online even if the warp core isn't.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 : Great point.  Added.  Thanks!  :-)